# Using the output of purrr::safely()

Tags: r, purrr

Suppose I have a very large list in R. Some of the values are valid and some are invalid. The example uses a list with only 6 elements.

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

myList <- list(-1, 0, 1, 2, 'poo', 'hi')

safe_log <- safely(log)

results <- myList %>%
  map(safe_log) %>%
  transpose()

allErrors <- results[['error']]
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Using `allErrors`, which elements of `myList` are invalid? I'm looking for an integer vector that returns:

```
[1] 5 6
```

2. Subset `allError` to show only the error messages. I expect this output:

```
[[5]]
<simpleError in .Primitive("log")(x, base): non-numeric argument to mathematical function>

[[6]]
<simpleError in .Primitive("log")(x, base): non-numeric argument to mathematical function>
```

3. Subset `myList` for only the valid values. I want a new list that looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] -1

[[2]]
[1] 0

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can check which elements contain some kind of error using `inherits`:

   ```
   is_error = allErrors %>% map_lgl(~ inherits(., "error"))
   ```
2. Once you've done that, subsetting the list is simple:

   ```
   which(is_error)
   allErrors[is_error]
   ```
3. Same with subsetting to get the valid values:

   ```
   myList[! is_error]
   ```

Comment: this is a beautiful answer. the `inherits` function is new to me. I also learned the difference between using `[` versus `[[` to subset a list. thank you.

Comment: As an alternative to step 1: `is_ok = allErrors %>% map(is.null)`